# py2app keeps adding "--iconfile" to DATA_FILES

Tags: python, py2app

I'm running py2app 0.13 on MacOS High Sierra over Homebrew python 3.6.

I have an icon file to use as the App's icon.
But running

`py2applet --make-setup setup.py --iconfile images/appicon.icns`

will end up with

`DATA_FILES = ['--iconfile']`

no matter where I place the `.icns` file.

Is this a py2app bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the issue by placing the option in front of the `--make-setup` like this:

```
py2applet --iconfile=images/appicon.icns --make-setup setup.py
```